# Orthanc Pacs Server and dcm4che3 ToolKit command findscu

Tags: dcm4che

I install an [Orthanc Server](https://www.orthanc-server.com/) ([PACS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_archiving_and_communication_system)) with WebGui, and upload a few dicoms from osirix dicom sample. I have a some problem with command findscu from package dcm4che3. When I called /findscu -c TEST@127.0.0.1:4242 -m PatientName="WRIX" , I have an error:

```
org.dcm4che3.net.AssociationStateException: Sta1 - Idle
    at org.dcm4che3.net.State.writeAReleaseRQ(State.java:223)
    at org.dcm4che3.net.Association.release(Association.java:271)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.findscu.FindSCU.close(FindSCU.java:463)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.findscu.FindSCU.main(FindSCU.java:380)
```

in orthanc log:

```
E0713 16:20:51.875545 main.cpp:180] Unknown remote DICOM modality AET: "FINDSCU"

E0713 16:20:51.875589 CommandDispatcher.cpp:776] Find requests are disallowed for the AET "FINDSCU"

E0713 16:20:51.875603 CommandDispatcher.cpp:852] DIMSE failure (aborting association): DIMSE Caller passed in an illegal association
```

I think I need to add in orthanc.json FINDSCU how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare your modality `FINDSCU`in the `DicomModalities`option of the [configuration file](https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/book/users/configuration.html) of Orthanc, otherwise Orthanc will refuse to answer for security reasons. More information is available in the Orthanc Book, in the section entitled "[Understanding DICOM with Orthanc](https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/book/dicom-guide.html#dicom-network-protocol)".